# How to install an old version of google chrome

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, downloads, google

I have the latest version of google chrome. I need to test an issue in an older version. How to install the old version? and this also requires disabling the auto-updates.

Comment: Exactly which version do you need? Also do you need google-chrome-stable or chromium?

Comment: I need google-chrome-stable. The version I need is: 69.0.3497.81

Comment: You can find older versions on [Slimjet](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php). The website has 69.0.3497.92

Comment: I need 69.0.3497.81 specifically. It does not seem available inslimjet. Also I can nt download from un-trusted sources.

Comment: Even if it may be trusted I need the exact google Chrome 69.0.3497.81. There is some change that Google made and I need to examine for research purpose.

Comment: You might like to read [Where can I get old version of Google Chrome?](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-get-old-version-of-Google-Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded the older version of chrome and it's only issue of installing it then disconnect your PC/Laptop from internet and try installing it that way, it'll prevent it from checking for update and if it get's installed, before connecting back to internet don't forget to turn off the setting to check for updates in chrome.

Note - don't download the installer for the chrome cause even if you have installer for older version it'll eventually download the latest chrome from the internet. Download the chrome application of older version and try.